# Class Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\CollectionFactory does not exist

Tags: magento2, not-found

I just finished a clean installation of **Magento 2.2.4**. When I try to add a product, it throws an error saying '`Class Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\CollectionFactory does not exist`' Please help how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the module is enabled. `php bin/magento module:status`

Second, make sure that you have run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

If you are not in developer mode, run`php bin/magento setup:di:compile` because new classes will not be automatically generated.

If you already are in developer mode, try deleting the generated/code directory.